# how to use c#/asp.net to call open or save file dialog in ie

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, api, internet-explorer

Im using a get blobentry to save a file locally onto my pc but i would like the ie open/save dialog to pop up instead. how would i do this? my code is:

```
 ARSServer.GetEntryBLOB("CHG:WorkLog", "CWL000000005407", 1000000351, "C:\\Users\\josephs\\Desktop\\word.doc");
```

which curently saves the file (from BMC server) onto my desktop as long as i have created the file name, can i get IE to handle this using code?

There is also the option of using "out byte [] content" but im not to sure how to use it

```
 ARSServer.GetEntryBLOB("CHG:WorkLog", "CWL000000005407", 1000000351, "out byte [] content"
```

Would this be the method to get ie to being the open/save dialog?

Comment: I don't think that there is any thing like `open` or `save` file dialog in asp.net. There is only one `file-upload` control in asp.net.

Comment: do you want to show the user a "Download" of the file ? where the user can save the file to their pc.

Comment: yes i would like to, at the moment its saving in a temp direcrory but not notifying the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET runs in a browser, for such, it uses the language for the browser to understand: **HTML**

for that the only File control that gives you the ability to ask for a file is the `<input type="file" ...`

in ASP.NET you can use the [**FileUpload**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx) control `<asp:FileUpload runat="server" id="...`

but you need to wrap it in a `<form>` and act upon fomr submittion (or by an async call, but always submitting the form)

a full demo code is [available in **MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx).